# Appending characters to the end of each line in Emacs

Tags: emacs

Assume I have a text file with content

```
1
123
12
12345
```

If I want to add an 'a' in the beginning of each line I can simply use string-rectangle (C-x r t), but what if I want to append an 'a' to the end of each line, after which the file should become

```
1a
123a
12a
12345a
```

Thanks.

Comment: Companion question, how to remove characters from the end of each line?: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108459/4671

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761706/in-emacs-edit-multiple-lines-at-once/774953#774953

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You could use `replace-regexp` for this purpose, with the `$` regexp metacharacter that matches end-of-line. Go to the start of the buffer, and then do `M-x replace-regexp`, and answer `$` and (your text) to the two prompts.

Or, in emacs-speak, for your specific example of adding `a`:

`M-< M-x replace-regexp RET $ RET a RET`

Comment: tbh, "keyboard macro" was my first thought, too, until I stopped and thought "there's got to be a simpler way".

Comment: Or `C-M-% $ RET a RET` to do the same thing more selectively with `query-replace-regexp`

Comment: @phils Your suggestion for some reason doesn't work.  That is obvious way - but doesn't work.  Try it yourself.

Comment: user619818: it works just fine, and I have used this myself on a great many occasions. I suspect you are mis-typing the key combination `C-M-%` which on US keyboards is `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Shift` + `5` (or use `M-x query-replace-regexp`)

Comment: And let's not forget that adding whatever at the start of each line is essentially the same, except using ^ instead of $, like so: `M-< M-x replace-regexp RET ^ RET Z RET`

Comment: How do we type RET in mac :(

Comment: @AkshayHazari `RET` is emacs speak for the Enter key ("Return")

Comment: @mogsie I know , just unable to type Enter key in string search and replace-string in OSX . In the terminal its ctrl and enter , but in emacs it doesn't work unlike when I had linux.

Answer (score 25):

Emacs keyboard macros are your friend.

```
C-x ( C-e a C-n C-x )
```

Which just sets up the keyboard macro by: starting the keyboard macro (<kbd>C-x (</kbd>), go to the end of the line (<kbd>C-e</kbd>), insert an `a`, go to the next line (<kbd>C-n</kbd>), and then end the macro recording (<kbd>C-x )</kbd>).

Now you can either execute it (<kbd>C-x e</kbd>), and keep pressing <kbd>e</kbd> for each line you want to have it run on, or you can run it on a region with <kbd>C-x C-k r</kbd>.

If you do this a lot, you can save the macro, or you can write a function.  This would be one such function:

```
(defun add-string-to-end-of-lines-in-region (str b e)
  "prompt for string, add it to end of lines in the region"
  (interactive "sWhat shall we append? \nr")
  (goto-char e)
  (forward-line -1)
  (while (> (point) b)
    (end-of-line)
    (insert str)
    (forward-line -1)))
```

Comment: I usually create such a macro by typing `F3 End a Down F4` followed by series of `F4`. I tend to prefer normal arrow keys and Home/End over the Emacsisms.

Comment: One additional useful piece of information is that of course hitting `e` a boatload of times is that you can combine it with `C-u` to repeat the task many times:  `C-u` `20` `C-x` `e` to get 20 repeats of the macro

Answer (score 0):

Another option is install the `multiple-cursors` package: https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el

Then you can mark (select) all of those lines and run `mc/edit-ends-of-lines` which will create a cursor at the end of each of those marked lines. Next type your text and it'll be added at each cursor.