# Deleting a char from the end of line in emacs

Tags: emacs, text-editor

I would like to use [these answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4870704/671013) to insert the char `%` at the end of each line in a marked region when using `emacs`. However, in order to avoid endings like `%%` I have to first delete all the occurrences of `%` at the end of the lines in the region. For example

```
foo%
foo2
foo3%
foo4%%
bar
bar%
```

should become

```
foo
foo2
foo3
foo4
bar
bar
```

Note that not all lines in the region end with `%` (otherwise I would be done), and some might end with more the one `%`. That is, one cannot simply delete the last char of each line. I guess it is rather simple, but I'm too much of emacs newbie.

Comment: `M-x replace-string` (usually `Alt-x` *replace-string*) then enter `%` replace with nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>C-M-%</kbd>`%+`<kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd><kbd>!</kbd> invokes `query-replace-regexp` replaceing any number of %'s followed by a newline by a newline.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do the two steps in one, replacing any existing % characters at end of line with only one.

```
C-M-%   <- query-replace-regexp
%*$     <- 0 or more %s at end of line
Enter
%       <- by only one %
Enter
!       <- apply to all (optional, see below)
```

If you are using Transient Mark mode, then the command will operate inside the active region. Otherwise, you may choose to `narrow-to-region` (<kbd>C-x n n</kbd>)to make sure it doesen't affect other parts of the file.